# How to implement a ' continuous call' syntax sugar in C language?

Tags: c

'continuous call' means a function call like this(I have no better words):

```
foo(arg1,...)(arg2_1,...);
```

It equivalent to:

```
foo(arg1,...);
foo(arg2_1,...);
```

I think we can return a pointer that who is itself to implement it.So this code worked well:

```
typedef int (*f_p)(); //*note* here I always must indicate a 'int' or any other type
f_p print_two_num ( int a , int b )
{
printf ("%d,%d\n", a, b);
return print_two_num;
}
//omit main()
print_two_num(1,2)(3,4);
```

But I can't call this function like:

```
print_two_num(1,2)(3,4)(5,6);
```

because `print_two_num(1,2)(3,4)` will return a 'int' type.(Although we can call it by `((f_p)(print_two_num(4,5)(2,3)))(6,7))`, but ugly.)
So we can change the code like this:

```
typedef int (*f_p1)();
typedef f_p1 (*f_p2)();
f_p2 print_two_num ( int a , int b )
{
//...
return print_two_num;
}
```

But it can't call like `print_two_num(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)(7,8)`,because it still will get a error on last call.

Now，how to implement unlimited 'continuous call',and I can call a function like:`foo()()()()()... ...`?

I can't find good way to solve the 'recursive-definition' problem.

I know this syntax sugar has no practical help, I'm just curious :P

Comment: For this to work you have to make a recursive type-alias (the `f_p` type-alias needs to reference itself) which is not possible. So in short it can't be done in standard C.

Comment: Why do you ask? Read more about [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you might have a macro `DO` which expands to some clever [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partial solution is not standards-conpliant, as evidenced by the compiler warning. You need an explicit cast to convert between pointer types. If you do use a cast, you invoke undefined behaviour, because you have to cast the pointer back to the original type before calling it.

You cannot use this exact syntax in C.

if you really want, you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct chain (*f_p)(int, int);

struct chain
{
    f_p also;
};

struct chain print_two_num ( int a , int b )
{
    printf ("%d,%d\n", a, b);
    struct chain ret;
    ret.also = print_two_num;
    return ret;
}

int main ()
{
    print_two_num(1,2).also(3,4).also(5,6);
}
```